# treating two different filenames as the same with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been around here long enough to know that not providing a sample of what I've tried is looked down on, but to be honest, I couldn't find anything close to what I need.

I have two files, `index.php` and `foldername`. I would like to access these same files by going to `index_sample.php` and `foldername_sample`. Basically, adding `_sample` to the URL wouldn't be looked at by apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?)_sample(.*)$ /$1$2 [L,NC]
```